# Angular Material: MAT-NAV-LIST - multiselect using CTRL

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to find a solution to avoid using checkboxes for multi selection in the mat-nav-list. I searched for any example but did not find it. Anyone has this figured out?

Thanks